# "Проект Эйлера". Задача.

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector

Решил порешать задачи из "Проекта Эйлера". Начал с самых простых, и тут возникла загвоздка.
Вот задача 14 (http://euler.jakumo.org/problems/view/14.html).
Вот её решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//проверка на чётность числа
bool is_odd(int number)
{
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

//вычисление самой последовательности Колатца
int cntNumsInCollatz_seq(int first_number)
{
    if ( first_number == 1 )
        return 1;

    if ( is_odd( first_number ) )
        return 1 + cntNumsInCollatz_seq( first_number / 2 );

    if ( !is_odd( first_number ) )
        return 1 + cntNumsInCollatz_seq( 3 * first_number + 1 );
}

int main()
{

    time_t time = clock();

    int length = INT_MIN;
    int number;

    for (int i = 100000; i != 2; i--)
    {

        int tmp_rez = cntNumsInCollatz_seq( i );

        if (tmp_rez > length)
        {
            length = tmp_rez;
            number = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Time of work: " << double(clock() - time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

    cout << length << endl;
    cout << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Тут просто рекурсивная функция, и всё. Для чисел `100 000` и меньше работает более-менее, но как только я хочу посчитать для чисел от `1 000 000` и меньше, программа падает, т.к., видимо, глубина рекурсии слишком большая.

Пытаюсь оптимизировать её путём `Меморизации`(сохранение ранее вычисленного результата с последующим обращением к нему), чтобы не вычислять одно и то же по `300` раз, т.к., к примеру, если вычислять количество шагов для `13`, то:

```
13 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

А если для `7`, то:

```
7 -> 22 -> 11 -> 34 -> 17 -> 52 -> 26 -> 13 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

Но так как на раннем этапе было вычислено количество шагов для `13`, то для `7` в последовательности начиная с 40 можно не продолжать вычисления, а взять готовый результат.

Пытаюсь это реализовать.
Работает в разы быстрее, но уже для `10 000` выдаёт ошибку `vector out of range`.

Как мне с эти справиться, если размер вектора увеличить больше нельзя? Да и это как-то накладно иметь вектор таких размеров. Помогите, пожалуйста. Тут нужен другой вариант, я предполагаю.

Вот изменённый код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//здесь добавил вектор
vector< int > numbers(1000000, 0);

 //проверка на чётность числа
bool is_odd(int number)
{
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

//вычисление самой последовательности Колатца
int cntNumsInCollatz_seq(int first_number)
{

    //здесь проверка на присутствие элемента в векторе 
    if ( numbers[ first_number ] != 0 )
        return numbers[ first_number ];

    if ( first_number == 1 )
        return 1;

    if ( is_odd( first_number ) )
        return 1 + cntNumsInCollatz_seq( first_number / 2 );

    if ( !is_odd( first_number ) )
        return 1 + cntNumsInCollatz_seq( 3 * first_number + 1 );
}

int main()
{

    time_t time = clock();

    int length = INT_MIN;
    int number;

    for (int i = 10000; i != 2; i--)
    {

        int tmp_rez = cntNumsInCollatz_seq( i );

            //здесь добавление элемента ввектор
        numbers[ i ] = tmp_rez;

        if (tmp_rez > length)
        {
            length = tmp_rez;
            number = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Time of work: " << double(clock() - time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

    cout << length << endl;
    cout << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @rekrut1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Судя по всему, последовательность может расти далеко за миллион, так что запомнить **все** промежуточные числа, наверное, не самая лучшая идея.

Кроме того, `odd` на английском значит **не**чётный, так что лучше вашу функцию переименовать.

Для начала давайте избавимся от ненужной рекурсии. Вместо рекурсии вполне можно воспользоваться итерацией:

```
int next_Collatz(int current)
{
    if ( is_even( current ) )
        return current / 2;
    else
        return 3 * current + 1;
}

int cntNumsInCollatz_seq(int first_number)
{
    int cnt = 1;
    int current_number = first_number;
    while (current_number != 1)
    {
        current_number = next_Collatz(current_number);
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Таким образом, мы не переполняем стек, если в последовательности встретится миллион элементов.

Затем мы можем запомнить длину последовательности для нескольких начальных значений `first_number` — например, для миллиона. :)

Получается следующее:

```
const int MEMOIZATION_RANGE = 100000; // произвольное значение, чем больше,
                                      // тем лучше, сколько память позволяет
vector<int> CollatzLength(MEMOIZATION_RANGE, -1);

CollatzLength[1] = 1; // важно

int computeNumsInCollatz_seq(int first_number)
{
    int partial_length = 0;
    int current = first_number;
    // цикл до какого-то уже вычисленного значения
    // цикл обязательно закончится, когда мы придём к одному из уже
    // просчитанных чисел (например, к единице).
    while (true)
    {
        if (current < MEMOIZATION_RANGE && CollatzLength[current] != -1)
            break; // нашли!
        // если нет, переходим к следующему
        current = next_Collatz(current);
        partial_length++; // ... увеличивая длину куска
    }
    // это полная длина:
    int length = partial_length + CollatzLength[current];
    // повторяем тот же цикл сначала, записывая данные в таблицу
    partial_length = length;
    current = first_number;
    while (true)
    {
        if (current < MEMOIZATION_RANGE)
        {
            if (CollatzLength[current] != -1)
                break;
            CollatzLength[current] = partial_length;
        }
        current = next_Collatz(current);
        partial_length--;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Осталось только запомнить максимум. С этим вы наверняка справитесь сами.

Comment: @VladD от души) Всегда помогаешь)

Comment: @rekrut1: Пожалуйста! Над интересной задачей и думать интересно!